# CFDocument PDF radio buttons and checkboxes are huge

Tags: pdf, coldfusion, cfdocument

I have a page that I am rendering using CFDocument to display the page in PDF format.
However, the checkboxes and radio buttons are out of proportion and displayed huge.
I tried using CSS to change it but it didn't work. Seems like the checkbox/radio button image generated in the PDF just gets chopped off instead of scaled down.
Does anyone know how to scale it down so it doesn't look so ugly and out of place?

Comment: I'm surprised that no one else has had this problem. I tested this in Firefox, Chrome, and IE and in all cases the radio buttons and checkboxes in the PDF are large and pixelated. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of gotchas in CFDocument, I think the one you are running into right now is that the document tends to scale unexpectedly unless you produce an HTML document that fits exactly into your page size. Try putting your entire HTML into a wrapper div with proper height and width styles. Sometimes this involves a lot of guessing and checking to get right. It's important to also know that CFDocument renders your html in an internal browser to create the pdf from that does not support all of the same CSS that modern browsers do. Stick to as basic styles as possible for best results.

Comment: Unfortunately that didn't work. I scaled it down so it'll fit on a page that is less than 100% but the radio and checkboxes in the PDF are the same large size as before